# NodeJs - Electron - jQuery ajax request to IIS

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, iis, electron

I try to send an ajax request from electron, but I always get the error 401.
So far I've found out it has something to do with the credentials.

Thats my basic code snippet:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://myURL.php",
    success: function(response) { console.log(response); }
});
```

But as I said, I only get a 401 here.
So i added:

```
xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }
```

But that doesn't work either. 
Anybody have any idea how to do this? If there's anything else, just ask.

Comment: do you have a token that must be send with the ajax ?

Comment: No, there's no token i need to send.